# windows .BAT Error The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: windows, batch-file, error-handling, command

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /od /b %* ^| tail -n 1') do SET MY_T2=%%a

echo %MY_T2%
```

running the above  .bat file in windows 7 enterprise command prompt terminal

```
c:\tools>t2.bat

c:\tools>for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /od /b ^| tail -n 1') do SET MY_T2=%%a
The system cannot find the path specified.

c:\tools>SET MY_T2=t2.bat

c:\tools>echo t2.bat
t2.bat
```

why do I get the error "The system cannot find the path specified."

If I change the above .bat file so that the output gets redirected to a file and then I set the variable from the redirected output file, I don't get the above error.

```
c:\tools>t1.bat

c:\tools>dir /od /b    | ttail -n 1  1>g:\t1.txt

c:\tools>set /p MY_T1= 0<g:\t1.txt

c:\tools>echo t1.bat
t1.bat

c:\tools>
```

How do I fix the Error without being forced to redirect the command output to a file ?

Comment: in the second code block you are using `ttail` instead of `tail`.Is that correct?

Comment: thanks. ttail.exe and tail.exe are identical. sorry for confusion.

Comment: I discovered why I was getting the error. Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I had earlier added [clink](https://mridgers.github.io/clink/) as a plugin to cmd, the command prompt. recently, I removed clink's directory but didn't uninstall it -- rendering a situation where cmd.exe was still searching for it. since cmd.exe didn't find clink, it was giving the error "The system cannot find the path specified."

That explains it all.